# Json Property indicating a private email in OutLook Email

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-api

I was trying to fetch the emails from OutLook using the microsoft's web api ( [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders('inbox')/messages](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders(%27inbox%27)/messages) ).

A User can mark an email as a private email by following the below path :

Draft -> Show Message Option -> Select 'Private' from the sensitivity drop down

Although this email is marked as a private email but I don't see any property in the response that identifies that email as a private email.

Kindly let me know if you which property which marks an email as private. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sensitivity is not in the message schema, but you can always request the `PR_SENSITIVITY` MAPI property:

```
$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'Integer 0x0036')
```

[image: PR_SENSITIVITY in JSON]